# Jquery BlueImp how to change filename before upload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

Is it possible to change the filename of the file being uploaded via jquery blueimp?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```html
require('UploadHandler.php');
class CustomUploadHandler extends UploadHandler {
    protected function trim_file_name($file_path, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range) {
            $name = 'First_' . microtime(true);
            $name = str_replace('.', '', $name);
            return $name;
        }
}

$upload_handler = new CustomUploadHandler();
```

In your custom file index.php initialize this function of UploadHandler.php

Comment: good non-hack solution. Thanks! 

there was a typo in your solution though, I'll edit it to fix it.

Comment: Yes! Thankyou so much

Comment: +1... but non hack solution?  he overwrites the trim function to change the filename? meh. It is the most non hack solution of the available ones.

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved with only change the trim_file_name() function to the following in the UploadHandler.php file.

```
protected function trim_file_name(VARIABLES) {
    $name = uniqid();
    return $name;
}
```

and that's all

Comment: Where is trim_file_name called from? I need to send the variable 'name' but cannot find a way to send it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a client-side solution specific to BlueImp. It uses [BlueImp's "add" callback](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API#callbacks). My example will strip commas from the filename.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
        $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
            //set new name here
            var newname = data.files[index].name.replace(/,/g, '');
            Object.defineProperty(data.files[index], 'name', {
                value: newname
            });
        });
        $.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(this, e, data);
    }
})
```

Comment: This is the only client side solution I've found that actually works. Btw, that code only replaces the first comma. You probably want `.replace(/,/g, '')` or `.split(',').join('')`

Comment: still works in 2022

Comment: Why do you need to call the function `$.blueimp.fileupload.prototype.options.add.call(this, e, data);` ? Won't this cause to call the function twice?

Comment: @EduardoMolteni the Add callback seems to be special. The docs require you to either submit the data or call the prototype function: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Submit-files-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

The name property of File objects is read only, but an alternative name can be provided as uploadName property for each individual file.

Can use callback

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload
  submit: (e, data) ->
    data.files[0].uploadName = 'newname'
```

If your data.files contains all files in one time you can iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open UploadHandler.php
2. Find

   `protected function handle_file_upload();`
3. Edit

```php
$file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, 'GiveYourNewName', $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution was posted by 'lethal.industry' user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358248/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-rename-files).
You must paste this code inside of UploadHandler class in UploadHandler.php file

```
   //custom function which generates a unique filename based on current time
    protected function generate_unique_filename($filename = "")
        {

            $extension = "";
            if ( $filename != "" )
            {
                $extension = pathinfo($filename , PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if ( $extension != "" )
                {
                    $extension = "." . $extension;
                }
            }

            return md5(date('Y-m-d H:i:s:u')) . $extension;
        }
```

You can modify the filename as you like change the last line 'return...'

Then you search the 'handle_file_upload' function in UploadHandler.php and replace this line

```
$file->name = $this->get_file_name($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range);
```

for this line

```
$file->name = $this->generate_unique_filename($name);
```

Comment: This method does not work with multi file activated, it works fine only when upload one file. Check my response below to find out a simple way to achieve this.